# Angular 6 routing works with ng serve, not Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

I feel like this is a dumb question but I'm new to Angular and can't find the answer anywhere...

I'm trying to set up routing in a new Angular 6 app. I can route to a component just fine when I serve from the command line using ng serve, but not when I serve from Visual Studio. This is just basic routing.

Routes defined in app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MaintenanceComponent },
  { path: 'merchants', component: MaintenanceComponent }  
];
```

router-outlet tag in app.component.html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Interestingly, I can tell that the router is recognizing a request to the root while running in VS, as it will return 404 without { path: '', component: MaintenanceComponent }. However trying to access /merchants returns 404 regardless. So that's a clue.

What simple thing am I missing?

The project uses .NET Core Web API.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when the client makes a request for /merchants, the server needs to return the index.html for the angular routing to kick in. The way to do that is with IIS URL rewriting by adding to your web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This tells iis to rewrite all request that are not valid files or directory to the / url

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm slowly sorting through this, and think I have similar solution in place. I'll post that here.